# SharedPreferences result in debugger error

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I just wrote this simple piece of code, but it doesn't work, but the debugger stopped my program. Any ideas? This is the line that probably causes the error:
`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();`

```
package com.***.juraquiz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentStatistics extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    int answers_total;
    int correct_answers_total;
    int wrong_answers_total;


    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("statistics", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("ANSWERS_TOTAL", 90);
    editor.putInt("CORRECT_ANSWERS_TOTAL", 82);
    editor.commit();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statistics, container, false);

    SupportFunctions.setViewBackgroundWithDrawable(view.findViewById(R.id.tv_heading_statistics), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_heading_background));

    TextView tv_answers_round = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_answers_round_value);
    tv_answers_round.setText(String.valueOf(Globals.getANSWERS_ROUND()));

    TextView tv_correct_answers_round = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_correct_answers_round_value);
    tv_correct_answers_round.setText(String.valueOf(Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWERS_ROUND()));

    TextView tv_wrong_answers_round = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_wrong_answers_round_value);
    tv_wrong_answers_round.setText(String.valueOf(Globals.getANSWERS_ROUND()-Globals.getCORRECT_ANSWERS_ROUND()));

    SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("statistics", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    answers_total = getSharedPreferences.getInt("ANSWERS_TOTAL", 0);
    correct_answers_total = getSharedPreferences.getInt("CORRECT_ANSWERS_TOTAL", 0);
    wrong_answers_total = answers_total - correct_answers_total;

    TextView tv_answers_total = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_answers_total_value);
    tv_answers_total.setText(String.valueOf(answers_total));

    TextView tv_correct_answers_total = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_correct_answers_total_value);
    tv_correct_answers_total.setText(String.valueOf(correct_answers_total));

    TextView tv_wrong_answers_total = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_wrong_answers_total_value);
    tv_wrong_answers_total.setText(String.valueOf(wrong_answers_total));

    return view;

}

private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String string,
        int modePrivate) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

This is what I get:

```
Pick [Android Application]
```

Pick [Android Application]
Pick [Android Application]
Pick [Android Application]
    DalvikVM [localhost:8600] 
Pick [Android Application]
    DalvikVM [localhost:8600]
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))
            
            FragmentStatistics.onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) line: 22 
            FragmentStatistics(Fragment).performCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) line: 1500
            FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) line: 927 
            FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, int, int, boolean) line: 1104
            BackStackRecord.run() line: 682 
            FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() line: 1467 
            FragmentManagerImpl$1.run() line: 440
            Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 730
            FragmentActivity$1(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92
            Looper.loop() line: 137 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5419
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1187 
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1003
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
        Thread [<11> Binder_3] (Running)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but you have a private method called `getSharedPreferences(...)`. This overrides the default Android `getSharedPreferences(...)`. When you call your own `getSharedPreferences(...)`, you return null, and trying to do anything on that object will obviously throw a NPE.

Comment: where do I have a private method called getSharedPreferences?

Comment: oh. eclipse must have created it.. thank you. didn't see and most of all didn't expect that!

Comment: agh it says its undefined when I call it like this `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("statistics", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`. Thats probably why I accidentally created it. how do I have to call it?

Comment: That method is found in the `Context` class. As `Fragment` does not extend `Context`, you can't call it directly from within the fragment. Instead, get the `Activity` hosting your `Fragment` and call the method on that, like this: `getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: works. :-) found it out in the very moment you told me btw. woah its complicated. i'm glad there are people like you out there. go on! big thanks to

Comment: You're very welcome! I was a beginner once too, and I learned from more experienced people. I figure it's only fair that I pass on my knowledge!

Comment: very true. Its a hard way :-) do you develop apps?

Comment: None for public usage. I'm currently developing an in-house scouting app for my robotics team.

Comment: And why not for public? Never considered making money with your skills?

Comment: If I had any killer app ideas I would in a heartbeat! Alas, I don't. Also, school is my primary focus in life right now :)

Comment: Ahh, how old are you? Well, the killer ideas will come and then you're making millions :D

Comment: I'm just 17. I can't wait for that idea!

Comment: The Midwestern US, and you?